# Flexbox, Как убрать часть текста?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

**Eсть 2 блока первый текст 2-й картинка
Как убрать часть текста с помощью flexbox при разрешении 768px**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

да можно вставить span и написать display: none; к примеру
Нашёл тут свойство text-overflow: ellipsis; но не применяется
Как поступить в такой ситуации?

Comment: а при чем тут flexbox? оберните текст в контейнер и дайте ему макс высоту + `overflow: hidden`; + google `multiline ellipsis`